# How do we create and release hold manually in paypal?

Tags: paypal, balanced-payments

I'm new to paypal i had used balanced payments in past.

consider the following scenario

> I'm running a business of renting vehicles when a customer registers
>   to rent i have to deduct the rent amount(no of days * rent amount per day) from his account and have a
>   hold for the deposit amount of the vehicle which will be returned to
>   customer when he returns vehicle

i went through paypal documentation but could not find how to create this hold manually

I'm looking for something equivalent to [CREATE HOLD](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html?language=bash#create-a-new-hold) and [RELEASE HOLD](https://docs.balancedpayments.com/current/api.html?language=bash#void-a-hold) of [balanced](http://www.balancedpayments.com) in PAYPAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the most appropriate mechanism in PayPal for the functionality you describe is authorization/capture.

You can let user authorize payment using PayPal Express Checkout API for the deposit amount and for the rent eamount. When customer returns the vehicle, you can capture the payment using DoCapture API call.

This model also supports multiple captures for the same authorization. Using that feature you can, for example, capture rent payments daily.